# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{\ln\left(\frac1{1+x}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Can you please give me some hints to evaluate
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{\ln\left(\frac1{1+x}\right)}\ ?$$
I'm stuck.

Comment: Try the Taylor formula near $x=0$ of the denomiator, it should not be complicated.

Comment: Or use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: And observe first that $\ln(1/(1+x)) = - \ln(1+x)$.

Comment: I'll try it, thank you guys!

Comment: Notice that $\log(\frac{1}{1+x})=-\log(1+x)$

Comment: @sambo14: If you solve it, remember that you can also answer your own question on this site.

Comment: @Regret Ok, thank you, I'll do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}{\ln\left(\dfrac{1}{1+x}\right)}=-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}{\ln(x+1)}$$
Now apply L'Hopital's rule:
$$-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}{\ln(x+1)}=-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos x}{\dfrac{1}{x+1}}=-\dfrac{\cos0(0+1)}{1}=-1$$

Answer (score 3):

This should help you:
$$\frac{\sin x}{\ln\left(\frac1{1+x}\right)} = - \frac{\sin x}{\ln (1+x)} = -\frac{\sin x}x \cdot \frac{x}{\ln(1+x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You can use logarithms' properties to simplify the limits. Then, recall that, as $t \to 0$,
$$\begin{align}\sin t \sim t\\
\log(1 + t) \sim t
\end{align}$$

Comment: But does it help me in this case? Because even with your hint I will get $\frac00$ right?

Comment: @sambo14: How so? You'll get $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac x{-x} = \ ?$$ Now, since $x$ isn't actually $0$, but very near to it, you can simplify the limit and get the result.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With equivalents:

$\sin x\sim_0 x$ and $\ln\dfrac1{1+x}=-\ln(1+x)\sim_0 -x $, hence $$\frac{\sin x}{\ln\dfrac1{1+x}}\sim_0 -1 $$
So the limit is $-1$.